# T-sql run 1st query and then CASE 2nd query and output data or 'No'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Hey all I am trying to output data if the @blah equals Yes but output 'No' if not.

This is my current query:

```
DECLARE @blah VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @blah = (SELECT 
   CASE WHEN 
      COUNT(email) = '1' THEN     'Yes'
      ELSE                        'No'
   END
FROM 
   usersTbl 
WHERE 
   email = 'someone@somewhere.com');
SELECT
   CASE WHEN 
      @blah =                     'Yes' THEN 
     (SELECT * 
      FROM 
         usersTbl 
      WHERE 
         email = 'someone@somewhere.com')
      ELSE                        'No'
   END
FROM 
   usersTbl;
```

Currently the error I am getting with the above is:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

What am I missing?

Comment: CASE is an expression. It is used to return a single value. It is NOT used to control flow.

Comment: I don't understand.  What is `@blah`?  Is the first assignment important?  Are you trying to output all the rows if any exist, but `'No'` if none do?  Do you want the result to have one column or many columns?

Comment: @GordonLinoff If its 'No' then it needs to output **'No'**. If its **'Yes'** then it needs to output the users data that's in the DB.

Comment: Aside: It's a bit unusual to take an integer like `Count()` and compare it to a string like `'1'`. Based on the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) the character will be duly converted to an integer. If the only choice other than `1` is `0` then it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact `Count()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use EXISTS here instead. Something like this.

```
if exists
(
    SELECT * 
      FROM 
         usersTbl 
      WHERE 
             email = 'someone@somewhere.com'
)
SELECT * 
      FROM 
         usersTbl 
      WHERE 
             email = 'someone@somewhere.com'
ELSE
    select 'No'
```

Comment: @StealthRT . . . In that case, you should accept this answer.